# Could not connect to remote server in webservices

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Help, I am getting this error when trying to connect to a webservice

```
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.xxx.XXX.XXX:80 at 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) at 
System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at WebServiceCloudRole.JoomlaService.servicewsdl.saveUserRegistration(String name, String lastname, String contactno, String username, String email, String organizationname, String organizationurl, String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String country, String postalcode, String srole, String sothrole, String startdate, String expirydate, String skucode, String productid, String paymentstatus, String subscriptiontype, String amountpaid, String licenseref, String userregistertype, String token) at WebServiceCloudRole.WebServiceCloud1.CreatePrimaryCaregiverRole(String sFirstName, String sLastName, String sMailTo, String sRole, String sOtherRole, String Credential)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question such as providing details of the connection, or the code that calls the connection. Also I would hazard that the service doesn't let you connect to it, hence the exception

Comment: You get this error when you you try to connect to a computer with specified port and the machine is not listening to it. are you able to access xx.xxx.XXX.XXX:80 using browser

Comment: right satpal   and   kolin ,what i did is i am calling a 1st web serice Method ,in that method it calls another web services,not all time it throws error but some time it throws error.